# Electron and photon relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, virtual-particles, photon-emission

While a photon is mass less but when it converts to an electron how mass can come into being ?

Answer (score 2):

Photons do not transform into electrons. Please study the [photoelectric effec](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html)t  and the [compton effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/photel.html) .

Photons, as bosons, are not conserved and can disappear in an interaction. Electrons cannot appear out of nothing unless in pairs of electron positron, as the electron quantum number is conserved in electromagnetic interactions.